# After installing "vim-plug", I'm unable to edit .vimrc anymore

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed "vim-plug" from the link below, and I suppose it's working properly for now.

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#vim

However, when I try to edit `.vimrc`, it just pass through the default display of vimrc and the process settles on this display below.

[image]

Any suggestion to get it back?

Comment: Did you put something like `PlugInstall` in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your vimrc, to see if it's something inside it that's causing this? Looks like it's calling `PlugInstall`, do you have it doing that every time you open Vim? I wonder if you're using sessions or something like that to preserve state... Also try the command `:ls` to list the existing buffers. You can also try `:buf .vimrc` (or same without the dot) to try to switch to your pre-existing buffer supposedly named `.vimrc`.

Comment: @chepner You're right. ```PlugInstall``` was in ```.vimrc``` so I've deleted it and now ```.vimrc``` behaves as I expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @filbranden Yes, every time I opened a file with vim <file>, then ```PlugInstall``` was automatically called and I had no way of seeing as expected operation. And I've deleted ```PlugInstall``` from ```.vimrc```, which I guess I accidentally add. I can now edit ```.vimrc``` and call ```PlugInstall``` after vim edit display show up. Thanks!